# How to generate PDF in a loop using wkhtmltopdf and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pdf, mongoose, wkhtmltopdf

```
    EmpModel.find({},function (err, employees) {
        for(var i=0;i<employees.length-1;i++){
          var pdfFileName= folderName+"/"+employees[i].empid+"-"+m+"-"+d.getFullYear()+".pdf";
          wkhtmltopdf.command = 'C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe';
            console.log(i);
            var emp = employees[i];
            console.log(emp);
            console.log(pdfFileName);
            console.log("------------");
            res.render('emp-template',emp, function(err, html){

              // console.log(html);
               $ = cheerio.load(html);

               var pdfContent=  $('#payslipContent').html();

               wkhtmltopdf(pdfContent, { output: pdfFileName });


            });
        }
    });
```

I am trying to read each documents from the mongodb using mongoose and generate the pdf using wkhtmltopdf. But documents other than first is not getting generated.

Comment: Are you using the wkhtmltopdf plugin?

Comment: I am using wkhtmltopdf npm

Answer (score 0):

I am using ejs template to create HTML string then I convert to PDF.

```js
    const employees = await EmpModel.find();

    for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {

     var pdfFileName = "invoice.pdf"// Set your filename here
     var template = "invoice" // Your template name 

     var html = ejs.renderFile(pathToTemplate + `/${template}.ejs`, 
          {
             data: employees[i], 
          }, 
          options, (err, htmlString) => {

          if(err){
       return err
      }

   wkhtmltopdf(htmlString, { 
    output: pathToDocument +"/"+ `${pdfFileName}.pdf`,
             pageOffset: 1,
             marginBottom: 24,
             marginTop: 0,
    }, (err, stream) => {
       resolve(pdfFileName)
   });
      
     });
 }
```